# SQL-запрос работает неверно

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

В данном запросе должны подгружаться данные о маршрутах, id которых нет в другой таблице. Вместо этого записи попросту дублируются.

```
SELECT tRoutes.ID_Route, tRoutes.sNameOfRoute from tRoutes
INNER JOIN tGroupsRoutes ON tRoutes.ID_Route <> tGroupsRoutes.ID_Route
```

Comment: 1) Все запросы перед тем как вставлять в свой проект нужно проверять прямо на БД либо с помощью инструментов самой студии либо в SQL Server Management Studio.2) помедитируйте над [этой картинкой](https://external-preview.redd.it/M5QHWsp2vgZ-3QDZ4m-qS58lsOUgDNHau8trSFzS8H0.jpg?auto=webp&s=cae9cdc438b71c9025d40dad4650801fdcae1ef8), пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tRoutes.ID_Route, tRoutes.sNameOfRoute from tRoutes LEFT JOIN tGroupsRoutes ON tRoutes.ID_Route=tGroupsRoutes.ID_Route WHERE tGroupsRoutes.ID_Route IS NULL
```